# How to return a specific variable's value from a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've got two sh files, which are "main.sh" and "sub.sh" i want to return a variable's value inside "sub.sh" and use it inside main.sh .There is so many "echo" command so i can't just return the value from sub.sh file. I need only **one** variable's value. How can that be possible?

**main.sh**

```
echo "start"

//how to get a variable from the sh below?
//dene=$(/root/sub.sh)

echo "finish"
```

**sub.sh**

```
echo "sub function"
 a="get me out of there"  // i want to return that variable from script
echo "12345"
echo  "kdsjfkjs"
```

Comment: You know, your syntax is not Bash.  For example, those aren't bash comments.

Comment: i edited the "variable a" line. changed to just "a". I need a command like "sh main.sh | grep "delimiter" "

Comment: just print the variable a only it get the value in main.sh process.

Comment: no, i cant change the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "send" the variable, do this:

```
echo MAGIC: $a
```

To "receive" it:

```
dene=$(./sub.sh | sed -n 's/^MAGIC: //p')
```

What this does is to discard all lines that don't start with MAGIC: and print the part after that token when a match is found.  You can substitute your own special word instead of MAGIC.

Edit: or you could do it by "source"ing the sub-script.  That is:

```
source sub.sh
dene=$a
```

What that does is to run `sub.sh` in the context of `main.sh`, as if the text were just copy-pasted right in.  Then you can access the variables and so on.

Answer (score 1):

### main.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "start"

# Optionally > /dev/null to suppress output of script
source /root/sub.sh

# Check if variable a is defined and contains sth. and print it if it does
if [ -n "${a}" ]; then
    # Do whatever you want with a at this point
    echo $a
fi

echo "finish"
```

### sub.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "sub function"
a="get me out of there"
echo "12345"
echo -e "kdsjfkjs"
exit 42
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export variable to shell session in sub.sh and catch it later in main.sh.

```
sub.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
export VARIABLE="BLABLABLA"


main.sh
#!/bin/sh
. ./sub.sh
echo $VARIABLE
```